# How to invoke code for use in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, combobox, invoke

Hi I want to use my code below for a thread. I have some example code for invoke but I dont know how to do it when it comes to my combo box selected item going to string.

This is what I have:

```
//My code
string cb1 = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();

//Example 1
textBox2.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox2.Text = ""));

//Example 2
textbox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate()
{
    //do something
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one if you want to go with `Example 1` (using a `Func<string>` delegate instead of an `Action` delegate):

```
string cb1 = comboBox1.Invoke((Func<string>) (() => comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString())) as string;
```

Comment: @guitarPH: No problem. This is my preferred way of talking to controls through threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
string newValue = "hi there";

if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
    textBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox.Text = newValue; });
else
    textBox.Text = newValue;
```

For particular code asked in question we can do it like

```
MethodInvoker mi = delegate
{
     string cb1 = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
};
if (InvokeRequired)
   this.BeginInvoke(mi);
else
   mi.Invoke();
```

Comment: No not the textbox..The //My Code is my question.

Comment: Hi your code has no error..but i cant access the string cb1. How can I?

Comment: Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Beta)); oThread.Start(); public void Beta()
   {//put that method invoker stuff here}

Comment: I mean your code works fine. But I'm getting this. "The name cb1 does not exist in current context", because I want to use it or display it.